# Windows Phone 8.1 - очень тормозит анимация Pivot Page при смене ориентации экрана

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1

Собственно сабж. Имеется примитивный C# проект с шаблоном Pivot Page и Lumia 830 (Snapdragon 400, если эта информация хоть как-то может помочь). При смене ориентации экрана анимация поворота страницы воспроизводится с тормозами. В стандартном приложении Outlook для Windows Phone аналогичная анимация воспроизводится плавно. В чем может быть проблема?